# Не получается интегрировать jenkins с git

Tags: git, jenkins

Интегрирую jenkins с git. Добавляю ssh ключ для авторизации, но всё равно пишет про пароль для приватного репозитория.

```
Help for feature: Repository URL
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h — https://github.com/xxx/grader-storage HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/xxx/grader-storage/'
```

И, разумеется, не клонирует

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема была в https. Для того, чтобы избежать этой проблемы, требуется указать вместо `https://github.com/xxx/grader-storage`, `ssh://git@github.com:xxx/grader-storage.git`